# Azure: Cross-region private links

Tags: azure

I am attempting to create a private link service that can be reached from a different region. I am getting conflicting information from Azure documentation, with [one link suggesting "global reach"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview) and [another link limiting that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-service-overview)

[Global reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuSBr.png)
[Limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBrZ3.png)

In practice, I have one private-resource-vnet in westus and one vnet in eastus. After creating a load balancer per the documentation in the private-resource-vnet, I add a private link to that vnet and resource, and attempt to link it to a private endpoint. The below sample shows adding an endpoint in both eastus (where the private link is) and westus (where the vnet to reach the link is)

```
PS Azure:\> az network private-endpoint create  --name privateEndpoint --resource-group MyResourceGroup --vnet-name clientVNet --subnet clientSubnet --private-connection-resource-id "/subscription/link/to/private/resource/in/eastus" --connection-name myPLS --location westus
This command is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
InvalidResourceReference - Resource /subscriptions/[...]/CLIENTVNET referenced by resource /subscriptions/[...]/privateEndpoint was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.

PS Azure:\> az network private-endpoint create  --name privateEndpoint --resource-group MyResourceGroup --vnet-name clientVNet --subnet clientSubnet --private-connection-resource-id "/subscription/link/to/private/resource/in/eastus" --connection-name myPLS --location eastus
This command is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: [...]. Resource /subscriptions/[...]/myPLS not found.
```

I would greatly appreciate some insight on what I'm missing here!

Answer (score 1):

Cross-region works with Azure services (SQL, Storage) that are behind Private Link. Customer owned services are limited to same region. Cross-region will be supported in the future.